# Cannot read property inside of setTimeOut, how i solve?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the state inside of setTimeOut

```
 change = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({
        categories: [...this.state.categories, { time: 20, msg: "msg1", visible:true }]
      })    }, 3000);
  };
```

in this this.state.categories i get the next error: "Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the callback you are providing to `setTimeout` is using the `function` keyword, which will have its own scope unless you bind it manually. You can fix that cleanly by making the callback an arrow function:

```
change = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      categories: [...this.state.categories, { time: 20, msg: "msg1", visible:true }]
    })
  }, 3000);
};
```

Based on your other comment, if you'd like to manually bind it instead, you can do this:

```
change = () => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    this.setState({
      categories: [...this.state.categories, { time: 20, msg: "msg1", visible:true }]
    })
  }.bind(this), 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function, you missed the `this` binding. Arrow function will do this for you implicitly.

```
change = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        categories: [...this.state.categories, { time: 20, msg: "msg1", visible:true }]
      })    }, 3000);
  };
```